# Detect state of location in flutter for Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, location, android-permissions

I am using the below method to detect users had allowed location permission all the time or not.
Is it possible to detect whether the user can selected the option for "Allow while using app" option in android?

import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
It consists of status values :

```
/// Returns a list of all possible [PermissionStatus] values.
  static const List<PermissionStatus> values = <PermissionStatus>[
    denied,
    granted,
    restricted, - But this only works for iOS and not for Android.
    unknown,
    neverAskAgain,
  ];
```

Is there another plugin which works for both Android and iOS and I can get the status of user action for location popup?

These are 4 option in location popup in Android
Deny
Never ask again
Allow only while using app
Always allow.

I wanted to detect when user click any of this states?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `permanentlyDenied` for android version

you can do this

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

static const List<PermissionStatus> values;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    values = <PermissionStatus>[
        denied,
        granted,
        permanentlyDenied,
        unknown,
        neverAskAgain,
    ];
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    values = <PermissionStatus>[
        denied,
        granted,
        restricted,
        unknown,
        neverAskAgain,
    ];
}
```

Comment: But in Android there are 4 option. Deny , Never ask again , Allow only while using app , Always allow. I wanted to detect all 4 states

Comment: it`s okay, just replace them

Comment: look at this [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/PermissionStatus-class.html) there are only 4 option exist for android and ios platform

Comment: Yes. That is true. That is why i am trying to find any plugin or any other way to get all status of location permission